# hide .mp4 from showing up when using img src=

Tags: php, html

can i hide the video file from showing up? when i tried to show only picture files, the video files inside the folder start showing up either.
here is my code, inside the folder, there are jpg files and mp4 files, i tried to show the image by using "img src=" but the mp4 files are showing up either. the mp4 files are blank and no thumbnail whatsoever i tried anything but still no luck, im new to this im sorry for asking this question.

```
<body>
<div class="photo">
<ul class="topic">
 <h1>Megan</h1>

    <?php
        $folder = "photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/"; //folder tempat gambar disimpan  
        $handle = opendir($folder); 
        $i = 1;

        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){  
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
    $file2=str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);
    $file3=substr($file,0);
            echo '<li><a href=photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/'.$file2.'.mp4>
            <img src="photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/'.$file.' " width="300" alt="" title="" />
            </a><br/></li>';  
        if(($i % 4) == 0){  
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';  
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
            }     
            $i++;  
        }    
    }  
    ?>
</ul>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you dont want to show the video on loading of page.Correct?

Comment: yeah.. thats correct, you can look at my website joyphotobooth.ddns.net:8123, you can see the null files, i just want to get rid of that

Comment: ok so when you want to show the video?

Comment: Your code is working the way it is supposed to.

Comment: i want to hide the video, because i have the thumbnail file which is the jpg files, so the files to process not big.

Comment: you need to use ajax

Comment: use javascript . When someome clicks on image thumbnail of the video, make a ajax call and load the video

Comment: is it a function on php or plug in?

Comment: to be honest , im really new to this.

Comment: ok 1 question, do you need to load the video on the same page or a different page?

Comment: If on a different page, you dont need ajax

Comment: on different page,

Comment: ok I will post an answer, please check it

Comment: let me explain it a bit, so.. i have this video, abc.mp4 and the thumbnail called abc_mp4.jpg, both on the same folder, so i tried to show only the thumbnail files, and i want to prevent the abc.mp4 files from showing up on the main page, its only showing when i clicked the thumbnail abc_mp4.jpg and the abc.mp4 showing up

Comment: Quote your attribute values, and look closely when you concatenate. This is a typo `$file.' "` < extra space maybe browser will fix that though..

Comment: im sorry, can i ask you.. do you mean quote, like $file2=str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);

Comment: Check ans @idnawsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change to your code

```
<body>
    <div class="photo">
    <ul class="topic">
     <h1>Megan</h1>


    <?php
        $folder = "photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/"; //folder tempat gambar disimpan  
        $handle = opendir($folder); 
        $i = 1;

        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){  
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
    $file2=str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);
    $file3=substr($file,0);
            echo '<li>'.
            '<a href="photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/'.$file2.'.mp4"><img src="photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/'.$file.' " width="300" alt="" title="" /></a>'.
            '<br/></li>';  
        if(($i % 4) == 0){  
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';  
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
            }     
            $i++;
            if($i==10)
               break;
        }    
    }  
    ?>
</ul>
<br class="clear" />
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: it says Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xamppp\htdocs\index.php on line 91 which is this line '<img id = '.$file2.' onclick="myfunction()" '+ 'src="photobooth/fredydanchenni/Animated/'.$file.' " width="300" alt="" title="" /> '+

Comment: and this Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xamppp\htdocs\index.php on line 92 which is '<br/></li>';

Comment: what happens if you click on image?check in console of browser as well

Comment: nothing happen, you can take a look, joyphotobooth.ddns.net:8123

Comment: you need to restrict the no of videos

Comment: too mnay videos are loading hence the page is not loading

Comment: cant you make it like using a href, so i can understand it , i just need it loading once it clicked

Comment: @idnawsi changed ans and restricted videos to 10. Dont try loading all files at one time

Comment: ok i think its start to working now, but it only shows 4 items

Comment: ohh i see... i got it

Comment: can you explain to me what did i do wrong on my first code

Comment: See you did nothing wrong. All you were doing was going through all files which was causing page to load very slowly

Comment: @idnawsi, if this code helped, mark it as the answer

Comment: hmm i tried to accessed it using mobile phone... and its still getting the mp4 file

Comment: you need to refresh the cache of mobile browser